# Extracting text contents of web-hosted PDF using C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-mvc-5

In C# (**ASP.NET MVC5**), I simply need to be able to extract the text contents from a **web-hosted** PDF and return them as a string.

I see plenty of (probably-old) examples of how to do this with a local file, but none of one that is web-hosted.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is your issue? converting a pdf file to text? or some web  related one?

Comment: Both.  :-)   Don't have a solution yet, but I was mainly look for assistance on the question of whether you can pull text from a web-based file.   Per below, seems like it is possible but smarter to pull it into the local server and process it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about web-hosted files is that you cannot see their contents unless your machine has a copy of that file. Even when you open a PDF file in your browser, it still downloads it to your machine, even if temporarily.

Therefore, a program cannot read a file it does not have.

So, you need to download the file into your filesystem, then reference it.

You could use the [WebClient class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to accomplish this:

```
using System.Net;
//...
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://website.com/mypdf.pdf", @"filepath.pdf");
```

From there, you can use one of those algorithms on "filepath.pdf", display the text, then delete that file.

Note: [Webclient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) is disposable. Make sure to dispose of it or make use of the [using keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

**Fair warning:** I'm not a security expert, but I would try to find ways to ensure the files aren't malicious, and ensure your PDF Reader algorithm accounts for this, or your application is specific to websites you know don't host malware.

Comment: not entirely true, one can always open a stream and perform read operation directly without storing the entire pdf on disk. Though it is a nightmare to parse the file that way so I will take your answer as a right statement.

Comment: Good point. Fair enough. I won't edit my statement, because you still need the data on your machine to read it, even if you do it one byte at a time, disposing of the previous (the use-cases of which are few).

Comment: When you say delete file, would this be the method you would take: `System.IO.File.Delete(@"filepath.pdf");` ?

Comment: Yes, but that method might only be for the full .Net Framework, and therefore only work on a Windows machine. I don't know if you're using Core. Either way, there are alternatives to deleting files.

Comment: Nah, just using full framework on this one.   Any particular PDF library that seems to have more support in C# land these days?